# Matrix vector moltiplication: how to return np.shape (d,)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, matmul

Here is an example code in Python:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.matrix([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
e1 = np.array([1, 1])

state = X @ e1
print(X @ state)
```

The matmul operand when doing a matrix vector multiplication returns the vector in the shape (2,1) instead of (2,), thus you cannot multiply the resulting vector by another matrix without having a mismatch.

To solve the error, I could use the reshape function after the multiplication to get the correct result.
But, I was wondering if there was a way to *directly* have the correct shape, since I have to do a lot of operations of this kind inside a for loop.

Comment: Did you read the `np.matrix` docs (any recent version)?  Is the result of the multiplication a array or matrix?

Comment: The result is a matrix, that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix`, it will solve your problem:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
e1 = np.array([1, 1])

state = X @ e1
print(state.shape)
# output: (2,)

print(X @ state)
# output: [1 1]
```

`np.matrix` is [deprecated](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) anyway:

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

Hope this will help!